# Multiple Linear Regression for House Price Prediction score is 0.28

Tags: machine-learning, python, linear-regression, prediction

I am trying to make predictions [using this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/tabular-playground-series-sep-2021/discussion/274684)

What I have done so far:

1. Dropped the `Administrative` column
2. Encoded the categorical data using `OneHotEncoder()` and `ColumnTransformer()`
3. Split the test and training data
4. Standard scaled the data (I did it to all the columns for matrix of features).
5. Applied LinearRegression score with x & y train is 0.05
6. Score with DecisionTreeClassifier is 0.92

I have seen online most people uses LinearRegression for this kind of prediction which is not working well me for me any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Linear Regression works well only if there is a linear relationship between the features and the output variable. To confirm this, please draw a scatterplot between each input variable and the output variable. Then you can see whether the features have a linear relationship or not.

Also, a heatmap will tell you how strongly each feature is related (either +ve or -ve) to the output variable.
Do some EDA like removing rows with null values and removing outliers in each feature.
Make sure you applied normalization and standardization in your data before prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some tips to get the best results:

1. Try to build your model with each and every type of algorithm you know. You never know which one will be the best for your dataset. Just because Linear Regression worked for others does not mean it is the best algorithm for the dataset.
2. Try to get the best features (feature selection) from your dataset. This may take some time as there are a lot of methods for feature selection, but by trial and error you can definitely get the best features.
3. For each and every algorithm you try, always perform hyperparameter tuning. It is a necessary step for most of the coplex algorithms (decision trees, random forest, gradient boosting etc.).